# How can I improve my query for not to get "PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size" (Ordering and paginating in laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, query-performance, laravel-paginate

I have a several items called posters that have logs. I want to order that posters by the date creation of these logs.

I have a model called Poster with this code:

```
class Poster extends Model {

protected $table = 'posters';

public function pos_log_resumenEnviado()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\models\PosterLog', 'pos_id')->where('log', 'Autores de poster enviado')->orWhere('log', 'Resumen de poster modificado')->latest();
}
```

Then in my controller I retrieve results like this:

```
$posters = Poster::with('pos_log_resumenEnviado', 'user')->where('state', 'Resumen pendiente de aceptacion')->get();

$posters = $posters->sortBy(function($pos)
{
    if( sizeof($pos->pos_log_resumenEnviado) > 0)
        return $pos->pos_log_resumenEnviado[0]->created_at;
})->take(1200);
```

I get all posters and then I order them and take the first 1200 results. This has been working fine (with a slow performance) but now I get the php error I said in the title. Error comes even before the *sortBy* execution, just with the *get()*

If I did not have to use *sortBy* I could use *paginate()* method but I dont know if there is another way to order that.

Comment: I seem that you are sorting your result with PHP, why don't you use MYSQL for this ?

Comment: Because I dont know how to use MYSQL to order by this field.

Comment: I don't use Laravel, but you should read the documentation to perform an order by with mysql. This will be faster and avoid the php memory limit error.

Comment: Thanks @Mcsky. I know how to use orderBy in mysql but I dont know how to use it with this specific field, because it comes from a model relationship. Anyway I get the error even before de ordering start executing.

Comment: it's better to use ordering with eloquent and not with php! will rise performance issues, check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct query you have to use
First, use where first to exclude the unwanted entries and then inside the with callback you can filter the results using eloquent :

```
$posters = Poster::where('state', 'Resumen pendiente de aceptacion')->with(['pos_log_resumenEnviado' => function($q){
                return $q->orderBy('poster_logs.created_at','ASC');
            }])->with('user')->get();
```

Comment: But how can I put the log creation date inside the orderBy? This is not a column of poster table.

Comment: when you're inside the  callback, you can access the pos_log_resumenEnviado directly, just put orderBy('created_at','ASC');

Comment: So many thanks. Now I can use paginate() and avoid the php memory error.  Unfortunatly now the order of items is not correct.

Comment: if you check the pos_log_resumenEnviado for each poster, are they order correctly?

Comment: I realized the problem is that "$q->orderBy('created_at','ASC');" is ordering by the 'created_at' of poster, instead of created_at of log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153226/discussion-between-juan-lopez-and-sletheren).